# Call a controller from another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I want to call another controller, I have these two

Ajax_controller

```
.
.
.
public function download_low_image($image){
$file = $this -> mimages -> get_image_file($image);
$test = new Thumb_controller();
$test->crop();

}
```

But returns

```
Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php
```

How can fix this?

Comment: Please add details to your question. It is very vague to make out anything from this

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help to solve your problem.
generallly , you can load other controller as

1. Load Controller inside your controller like

   $this->load->library('../controllers/Thumb_controller');
2. then simply call the method

   $this->Thumb_controller->functioname();