# how to access more than 2 controllers data into a single controller in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I am stucking in a code .I have 5 different `Controllers` page in admin folder like `controller_A.php` ,`controller_B.php` ,`controller_C.php` ,`controller_D.php` ,`controller_E.php` , Now I want to access method or function of 4 controller A ,B ,C ,D into Controller E method. 
Please help me , how to call 4 different controller method into other controller.

Comment: You might need HMVC for that https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: did you check some other answer like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter

Comment: Yes i have checked Vivek , i am able to access one controller data into another bt i want to access 4 different controller data into single controller.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/38699894/6369494](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38699894/6369494) check my comment here this will help you

Comment: Codeigniter is MVC which loading controllers with in controllers is not the MVC way how every as I have suggested up top HMVC better option. Because if you try some of the other answers when you try autoload some libraries you might run in to issue

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help to solve your problem. generallly , you can load other controller as

Load Controller inside your controller like

```
$this->load->library('../controllers/Your_controller');
```

then simply call the method

```
$this->Your_controller->functioname();
```

Comment: Thanx but this will call only one controller , i want to call 4 different controllers

Comment: have you tried with 
`$this->load->library('../controllers/first_controller');`
`$this->load->library('../controllers/second_controller');`
`$this->load->library('../controllers/third_controller');`
`$this->load->library('../controllers/fourth_controller');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below strategy:

```
require_once('controllers/controller_B.php');

$obj_b = new controller_B();

$obj_b->function_b();

require_once('controllers/controller_C.php');

$obj_c = new controller_C();

$obj_c->function_c();
```